# Sencha Touch: TabPanel with bottom TabBar not working when using Stores

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

We're developing a simple app with the sencha framework
The app consist of a few tabs( a tabPanle with bottom tabBar) and the switching between tabs works perfectly when we use it as it is on the sencha docs, alas when no live data is present.

When we add stores within the single tabs, functionalities breaks, tabs stop switching and every time one clicks a tab to change the view, a flickering appears, the default tab is loaded again(from the chrome console we can see that all the remote data request of the loginView get reissued) and the only tab that remain visible to the user is tab[0].

app.js --> http://pastebin.com/S9qaNfij
mainView.js ---> http://pastebin.com/uiG2E0AW
controller.js ---> http://pastebin.com/8MTfxC85

This was created with senchaArchitect, that btw is awful and quite useless if not to work visually with the components.

here is a little movie of the thing happaning.
http://youtu.be/OVOSOWhMZeE

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: controller pastebin link is broken.

Comment: I would suggest a few things: (1) put your project on sencha fiddle so it is live and others can try and fix the code. I saw some of your code but it wasn't fully clear to me how these stores were loading. (2) Did you want them to load on each tab switch? In which case perhaps best to listen for the painted event (I think that is correct, check the api docs). Perhaps it breaks trying to load before other tasks are complete? If you want to load everything first do your store load in the launch function, but probably best to do it on tab switch your app will seem a bit faster perhaps on startup.

Comment: Also paste the errors shown in the console when you try and switch tabs

Comment: No error occurs, only the behaviour shown in the video.
this is a test project so i do not really care about speed now.
BTW i put everything on senchafiddle, 
www.senchafiddle.com/#b7PIt
But the webservices are internal to our intranet and will not be disclosed and unfortunately today i have no time to set up mockup data for the stores.
BTW the code is all there.

Thanks!

P.S. @downvoter, care to comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's your button listener, it seems that it might be being triggered on even the tab panel button taps. I would try giving your button a unique ID and then create a ref and an action to login based on that ID.

Comment: yes was indeed the tap listener.
I used a ref and now it works fine.
Thanks.